# RESTful Web Services from Database error 500

Tags: mysql, web-services, rest, netbeans

I follow this tutorial on the official website of Netbeans : https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html#test-rest

I use Netbeans 8, Tomcat 8, Java EE 7 and MySQL

And every things work until I test my **RESTful web service from a database**, my database is named **Article**, I obtain this error :

```
   Etat HTTP 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

type Rapport d''exception

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

cause mère

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.rest.service.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:41)
    com.rest.service.ArticleFacadeREST.findAll(ArticleFacadeREST.java:66)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note La trace complète de la cause mère de cette erreur est disponible dans les fichiers journaux de Apache Tomcat/8.0.24.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: error 500 has nothing to do with database. webservice reaches an exception at this point     com.rest.service.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:41). AbstractFacade seems not initialized

Comment: Ok, but the code is the code generated by default by Netbeans when I create a web application and then I add a RESTful web service from a database to my web application using the Netbeans wizard to do this, I didn't change the code. There is no error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is a HTTP 500 error, which means internal server error, which in turn means that you have an unhandled exception.

From the information that you have posted, the error is a null pointer exception in your (generated) java code.

Your error appears to be related to the jersey libraries. From your tutorial:

> If the output window shows an error message that one or more classes
>   fails to exist and the project does not build, add the Jersey
>   libraries to the compile-time libraries. Right-click the project node
>   and select Properties. In the Properties tree menu, select Libraries.
>   Click Add Library and browse for the Jersey libraries

Could be related to how these are added / setup

Comment: Does the problem come from a problem of connection to my database, maybe there is a problem of connection to my database and the values which are stored in my database can't be provided to the entities, is it possible ?

But I verified that the mysql driver was in the lib folder of my project and that it used the same version that is used in the connection to my database according the connection in the Servers tab.

Comment: The Jersey libraries are included by default in my project  when I am creating a RESTful Web Service